# Set a prototype for a predefined object in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, prototype, javascript-objects

How can I manipulate the `prototype` of a predefined object (for example an `Array`) so that it does something when creating instances of that object?

Simply I want to `alert('an array was created!')` whenever an Array is instantiated.

Comment: That's tricky, given that you can create an array using `[123]` as well. Not sure if it's possible at all.

Comment: It is considered to be a bad practice - to modify the built-in types.

Comment: You might be able to replace `window.Array` with a completely different constructor of your own, which then proceeds to instantiate an actual `Array` (which you would need to have saved somewhere, since you don't have it anymore at `window.Array`) and return it. Still, not really advisable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to override `Array` with your own function.  It seems to work when doing `new Array`, but not when doing `[]`.

```
(function() {
    var _ac = Array;
    Array = function() {
        alert('an array was newed!');
        return _ac.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}());
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/DAg9A/

Comment: [Specs](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.4): `[]` uses `Array`, "where Array is the standard built-in constructor with that name.".

Comment: I never said you should do this, but you can :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can set a new method on an array by adding it to the `Array.prototype` object:

```
Array.prototype.fizz = function () {
    alert('works');
};

var arr = [];
arr.fizz();
```

However, this only allows you to create new methods, this does not allow you to extend existing methods*, nor does it allow you to override the `Array` constructor.

***Be careful adding new methods to existing types.*** This can adversely affect the entire scripting environment, and cause unexpected behavior in some libraries. Although some might call it "bad practice", it's quite common to use polyfills for cross-browser compatibility, such as by creating [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

There is no such thing as a "newed" array, the word is "instantiated":

```
var a1, a2;
a1 = []; //a1 was instantiated with a new Array
a2 = new Array(); //a2 was also instantiated with a new Array
```

There is no cross-browser means of overriding the `Array` constructor.

<sub>* it's possible to wrap an existing method in a function so that, when called, the existing method performs its original functionality, in addition to the new functionality. Although this might be referred to as *extending* an existing method, it is in fact creating a new method.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the you just create an array namespace for it:

```
array = {};
array.create = function() {

    alert("Created an array");     
    return [];

}
```

So whenever you create an array you use: array.create(); .

You should not, and in this case can not, change native functionality. You have to be in charge of every array creation.